# Pivot table with keeping non consecutive repeated values pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a large that set that look like below

[image]

Where the pattern of Event is always -IN Then OUT

And I want to arrange the table to look like:

[image]

Using pivot table immediately on the data will result on one [In][Out] per bayid

```
H= pd.pivot_table(data, index=['place',  'zoneid', 'bayid'], columns=['Event'],values='timestamp', aggfunc=lambda x: list(x))
```

So, I thought of creating a new column that gets the same value for each [In/Out] pair before using pivot table
[image]

My attempt is as the following, but it does not start the index count in every new group which resulted in some wrong values in the pivot table

```
D['index'] = (D.index)
D['index']=D['index'].shift(-1).fillna(len(D)).apply( lambda x: math.ceil((x)/2))
```

How I can arrange the table?

Comment: Can you add this data as text and not an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
data["_counter"]=data.groupby(['place',  'zoneid', 'bayid', 'Event']).cumcount()
H=data.pivot(index=['place',  'zoneid', 'bayid', '_counter'], columns=['Event'],values='timestamp')
```